# Debian - Detecting and mounting a logical volume/softRAID array

Tags: linux, debian, raid, lvm, logical-drive

I have an HP Proliant ML10 v2 server with a B120i raid controller.
Server has 5 disks, 2 logical volumes configured via HP Smart Storage Administrator (4x 3TB drives in RAID 0 is the first logical volume, and a 500GB ssd is the second logical volume where OS is installed and booting Debian 11).

This machine previously had Windows server installed, and could see the logical volume as 1 large 12TB disk in diskmgmt.msc. This is where the volume was originally created and used. Once Windows tanked I decided to switch over to Linux.

In debian, I can only see the individual drives, no logical volumes. I have been reading and troubleshooting all day and read that linux can "see through" logical volumes to present the actual disks, but none of the solutions I've found have helped me find, identify, activate, and mount my RAID array. These drives have data on them so I'm not trying to wipe them.

As you can see, the 4 drives are showing up as "Microsoft Basic Data" as the format.

I believe my logical volume may be /dev/sdd1. This volume gives unique output when trying to mount it from the others. Saying I need to "activate it and map a different device under /dev/mapper directory"... however none of the dmraid commands seem to do anything.

Things I've tried:

- Installing lvm2 logical volume manager (service is masked).
- My /dev/mapper dir is empty- all but a file called "control"
- 'sudo vgs', 'sudo lvs' and 'sudo vgscan' run but return nothing
- 'sudo dmraid -ay' returns "no raid disks".
- 'sudo testdisk' does return all 5 disks correctly
- booting into HP SSA raid config utility shows the 2 logical volumes as healthy and working

Some outputs:

**fdisk -l:**

```
root@ORION:/home/matt# sudo fdisk -l
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFRX-68E
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1376103F-A14B-4C50-8572-AC294E2226B3

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 5860532223 5860530176  2.7T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sde: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: MTFDDAK512TBN-1A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x76b94400

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sde1  *         2048  998215679 998213632  476G 83 Linux
/dev/sde2       998217726 1000214527   1996802  975M  5 Extended
/dev/sde5       998217728 1000214527   1996800  975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: ST3000DM001-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 959EC721-56CF-4EE0-AD2D-56D3EC83114D

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2  32768 5860530175 5860497408  2.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: ST3000DM001-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BAD41F4C-CAE2-4679-AC01-6CCDF4E19996

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1     34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  32768 5860530175 5860497408  2.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdd: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA DT01ACA3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x80fa0768

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *     2048 1126399 1124352  549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

**sudo blkid:**

```
root@ORION:/dev/mapper# sudo blkid
/dev/sda: PTUUID="1376103f-a14b-4c50-8572-ac294e2226b3" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sde1: UUID="557bf79c-82ba-4fee-b53e-ca895e66cb3b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="76b94400-01"
/dev/sde5: UUID="cd0f4e38-e2f3-4c34-8b75-3f95f849c86c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="76b94400-05"
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="a5de2645-8850-4914-b7b0-30f95d0fcd6e"
/dev/sdb2: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="98133779-1933-4284-b0ea-7bb73b22a14c"
/dev/sdc1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="72d203c4-6b37-420d-986e-0d076321dd21"
/dev/sdc2: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f428813b-52f4-4f27-bd18-8e0274840784"
/dev/sdd1: PARTUUID="80fa0768-01"
```

**parted -l reports:**

```
root@ORION:/dev/mapper# sudo parted -l reports
Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sda
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? Ignore                                               
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? OK                                                             
Model: ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      16.8MB  3001GB  3001GB               Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      16.8MB  3001GB  3001GB               Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  577MB  576MB  primary  ntfs         boot


Model: ATA MTFDDAK512TBN-1A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  511GB  511GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      511GB   512GB  1022MB  extended
 5      511GB   512GB  1022MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

**sudo mount -t /dev/sdd1 /mnt/dir:**

```
root@ORION:/dev/mapper# sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdd1 /mnt/raid
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x7338473b  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 36301  usa_count: 8638: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x7338473b)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

> In debian, I can only see the individual drives, no logical volumes. I have been reading and troubleshooting all day and read that linux can "see through" logical volumes to present the actual disks,

This is because Bxxx-series "Dynamic Smart Array" controllers are [software-based](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/api/document/c04441385#page=5) "fake RAID" controllers rather than hardware RAID, so it's not that Linux was deliberately trying to "see through" the logical volumes, but rather that's the default state – the OS is responsible for *setting up* the logical volumes in the first place. The controller only provides battery-backed write cache and a place to store array metadata (and possibly some acceleration), but not much else.

As the Bxxx manuals note, the controller requires Windows drivers to be provided at installation time. Similarly, HP provides Dynamic Smart Array drivers for Linux (RHEL and [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehp-iss-team/+archive/ubuntu/hp-storage)) and you're supposed to load the `hpvsa` driver while *disabling* the built-in SATA AHCI drivers. (Reddit claims that CentOS 8 comes with the driver built-in, but I wouldn't expect to see it in mainline Linux, as the driver is where all HP proprietary "advanced RAID algorithms" are.)

HP doesn't store array metadata on disk the way Dell does, so there's nothing for mdadm nor dmraid to recognize (and LVM most definitely won't recognize non-LVM arrays in any case), though it might be possible to assemble a "raw" RAID 0 array by hand using dmraid (but don't ask how).

My suggestion would be to back up all data, switch the B120i into standard SATA AHCI mode, then create new software RAID arrays using mdadm (or striped filesystems using ZFS or Btrfs).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Problem is, I haven't been able to access the data on the drives at all.. also I don't have anywhere else to put ~10TB of data for a backup. I haven't tried re-installing Windows to see if Windows will recognize the array; but then again I don't want to run Windows. So I guess my options then are either lose the data and re-create the array in Debian, or switch back to Windows and hope it can recognize/use the array.

Comment: Well, I actually suspect that you already lost the data when you installed Debian on the /dev/sde disk -- are you sure it wasn't one of your RAID0 member disks?

Comment: Yes, when in the HP RAID configuration utility, /dev/sde (the 500gb ssd, where debian is installed) is configured as a separate logical volume/array than the 4x 3TB drives in a RAID 0 configuration. If I remember correctly, this is how the boot/OS drive had to be configured to get any OS installer to see the SSD at all during installation while the B120i is in RAID mode. 
I see articles about people use RHEL 'hpvsa' driver; claiming it works for Centos7 and Ubuntu (so maybe Debian also) but installing hpvsa package didnt work, will try to disable ahci and install driver during install

Comment: Try manually `insmod`-ing the .ko and see if it's accepted -- it'll need to match the kernel version fairly closely; it should work across distros but only with similar kernels. / I'd be slightly worried about using a 4-disk RAID 0 array with no backups, really.

Comment: thanks again. This isn't work/company data. I threw this old server together with unused disks and use it as a seedbox. So while I would really like to avoid losing the data, it wouldn't be the end of the world... which is why I opted for more space over redundancy